# How to dynamically create associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am currently doing this but it isn't working:

```
var tempArray=new Array();
var number = 15;
tempArray[number]='blabla';

           for (var key in tempArray) {
                        alert(tempArray[key]);
                    }
```

the output that I get is:

```
in_array function (element) { var retur = false; for (var values in this) { if (this[values] == element) { retur = true; break; } } return retur; }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There are no associative arrays in JavaScript; there are only objects.

Comment: @Gumbo... Basically there are... Objects actually act as associative arrays.

Comment: i ran your code and it worked as expected, couldn't reproduce your output.  even with an intentionally bad array index all i got was 'undefined'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In JavaScript we use Objects.

```
var obj = {};

obj["15"] = "blabla";
obj.fifteen = "blablah";

for(var i in obj) {
    alert(obj[i]);
}
```